# Sending Array to php via ajax.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm storing an array and sending this via ajax...

```
var heart = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42,43];
// Sending this data via ajax to php file/ 
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 data:{ 'system': heart }, 
 url: "login-function.php",
 success: function(msg){
 alert('yes');
}
});
```

I believe its sending correctly because i'm getting a alert saying yes. 
This is my php file:

```
$system = $_POST['system'];
echo $system;
```

Am I storing this into a variable right ? How can i echo this value onto the page?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: `if( isset( $_POST['system']  ) ){$system = $_POST['system'];}` use check it using isset if it is available .

Comment: use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` because it is array instead of `echo`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues. A: you are not using the ajax return value, in your code `msg` - this contains the output from php, so to display it, add it to the page somehow:

html:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

js:

```
 var heart = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42,43];
 // Sending this data via ajax to php file/ 
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data:{ 'system': heart }, 
     url: "login-function.php",
     success: function(msg){
         $('#result').html(msg);
    },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

B: You cant just echo an array, its not a string. to display ist contents you can use a number of php functions, for example `var_dump()`:

```
$system = $_POST['system'];
var_dump($system);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, its very strange because i'm not getting alert messages. Its just for testing purposes so displaying an array in a alert box would do the job

Comment: @Ryan there isnt an `alert()` call in my code, so im not sure where you are going wrong. If you have an error in your php, the server may send a non 200 status code, in which case the `success` function will not get called. Ill amend my answer to cover that

Comment: See amended code - look in your js console for any output indicating a server error

Answer (score 0):

you can use `print_r( $system );` or use a `foreach` statement:

```
foreach ( $system as $itm ) {
    echo $itm . '<br />';
}
```

edit: `echo`ing in PHP is only available for strings, intergers etc; not arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$system = $_POST['system'];
print_r($system);
```